# Ошибка импорта при запуске контейнера Docker

Tags: python, aiogram, docker, docker-compose

Когда запускаю `docker-compose.yml` на windows, вылезает ошибка, хотя в коде все правильно.

С пакетами точно ошибок нет, все проверял 2 раза, возможно проблема с импортами, которые начинаются с точки, но тогда как их заменить?

Ошибка:

```
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container astrodb  Created                                                                                      0.0s
 ✔ Container tgbot    Created                                                                                      0.0s
Attaching to astrodb, tgbot
tgbot    | Traceback (most recent call last):
tgbot    |   File "/app/run.py", line 2, in <module>
tgbot    |     import src.main
tgbot    |   File "/app/src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
tgbot    |     from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
tgbot    |     from .client.bot import Bot
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 24, in <module>
tgbot    |     from ..methods import (
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/methods/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
tgbot    |     from .add_sticker_to_set import AddStickerToSet
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/methods/add_sticker_to_set.py", line 5, in <module>
tgbot    |     from ..types import InputFile, MaskPosition
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/types/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
tgbot    |     from .callback_query import CallbackQuery
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/types/callback_query.py", line 15, in <module>
tgbot    |     class CallbackQuery(TelegramObject):
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 292, in __new__
tgbot    |     cls.__signature__ = ClassAttribute('__signature__', generate_model_signature(cls.__init__, fields, config))
tgbot    |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/utils.py", line 258, in generate_model_signature
tgbot    |     merged_params[param_name] = Parameter(
tgbot    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
tgbot    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 2722, in __init__
tgbot    |     raise ValueError('{!r} is not a valid parameter name'.format(name))
tgbot    | ValueError: 'from' is not a valid parameter name
tgbot exited with code 1
```

Код:

```py
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from loguru import logger

from .config import config
from .db.base import check_db_conn
from .misc.scheduler import start_scheduler
from .payments.payment import start_payments
from .routes import register_all_routes
from .worker import start_worker
```